# Comparing the values within a specified range

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison

I am working on a program in python and need to compare that two values to see if they are within the 10% range of each other. I am not getting what code I can implement to handle this.

For example, for one item the value of **fat** is *100* and for the other it is *110*. Now I want to check whether both of the values are within the 10% range of each other and if this condition is met I have to print something (I can do it). I just want to know what to write in the if condition of the program.

EDIT: This is what I have currently

```
if button_id == 'middle':
      if mydict['cholesterol'] <= 0.10*mydict1['cholesterol']:
          tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Correct', 'You got it right')
      else:
          tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Wrong', 'You got it wrong')
```

I am stuck in the second IF condition, where I have to check whether the values are within the 10% range of each other.

Comment: It depends what you mean by *"within 10% of each other"*. 10% of which of them? What if they are one way but not the other? And in any case, SO isn't here to write your code for you.

Comment: I am not asking the code to be written, just the condition in 'if' statement!. For e.g. if one value is 100 its 10% is 90 and 110 so the other value has to be in between this range and this goes for both.

Comment: And that's some of your code; why do you think someone else should be writing it? Where precisely are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if value1 + (value1 * 0.1) >= value2 or value1 - (value1 * 0.1) <= value2:
    print("Values are within 10 percent margin")
```

In other words,

if value1 + 10% of value1 is greater than or equal to value2

or

if value1 - 10% of value1 is lesser than or equal to value2

Then the values are within 10% of each other.

Comment: Note that `* 1.1` and chaining comparisons would significantly simplify this

Comment: Whoops, turns out * 1.1 will work for +10%, but not for the -10% check.

Comment: Well, yes, then you need `/ 1.1` or `* 0.9`.

Comment: I'll just leave is at it is, since it hopefully answered the poster's question.

Comment: Thanks it really worked. I have marked it as a write answer and have voted you. Will be hopefully asking for more questions today but before I will try myself. Thanks